# Isekai manga where the mc is reincarnated through his own magic

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

The MC reincarnated himself through his own magic after his party defeated the demon king. Before he used his magic to do so, he took the daughter from the demon king and traveled with her over the world.

After he used his reincarnation magic he was born in a noble family where the daughter of the demon king is now working as a maid in this family. He also has an older/younger (not sure) brother. Through his knowledge he starts his training of body, swordsmanship and magic as a baby. Years later his brother wants to play with him but he denies him every time. But one day he accepts it to play tag. His brother can't catch him. After that, he requests from the mc to teach him his magic. He denied again, but made an offer. Only when he can catch him, would he teach him his magic.

I hope I'm not mixing up different mangas.

Comment: Because the term often gets used interchangeably with "reincarantion", is this an *isekai* portal fantasy with the main character being transported from another (maybe our own), or is he part of the setting.

Comment: No, as far as i know he isn't from another world. Maybe his first life was on earth and was mentioned briefly in the beginning, just like "The Strongest Magical Swordsman Ever Reborn as an F-Rank Adventurer". But probably not.

Comment: so he is an isekai live 2nd life then die then reincarnated and now it is his 3rd life (Like X dragon era) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for *[Rettougan no Tensei Majutsushi: Shiitagerareta Motoyuusha wa Mirai no Sekai wo Yoyuu de Ikinuku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/119997/Rettougan_no_Tensei_Majutsushi__Shiitagerareta_Motoyuusha_wa_Mirai_no_Sekai_wo_Yoyuu_de_Ikinuku)* (or in English *'The Reincarnation Magician of the Inferior Eyes'*) by Hiro Touge and Yusura Kankitsu.

> Abel was a genius magician who held immense power in a world where the color of your eyes indicates how powerful you are. However, the strength that came with his amber eyes was so great, even his comrades looked at him with fear and contempt. He therefore decided to transfer his soul far into the future, hoping to find a paradise that accepts him. He would soon find out that people’s attitude regarding his eye color did change, but not quite the way he had imagined...

It checks everything you described even if some of them are a bit mixed up like the little brother part. The brother you remember is in fact the youngest son of the noble family the demon girl is serving but he is not blood-related to the MC.

[image: MC and youngest son playing tag]

Answer (score 0):

Partly it sounds like [元最強の剣士は異世界魔法に憧れる](https://www.comicride.jp/book/motosaikyou/) (Moto Saikyou No Kenshi Wa, Isekai Mahou Ni Akogareru).

Comment: Why did this match? You can [edit] in more information.