Manga in which the main character gets reincarnated after many years into a little boy's body and finds an elf/demon woman he saved before he died
There's this one manga where the main character gets reincarnated after many years and, when he steps outside of the cave, he finds an elf/demon woman whom he saved before he died (she was a little girl; now she's grown up).

Is this The Reincarnation Magician of the Inferior Eyes...?

Abel was a genius magician who held immense power in a world where the color of your eyes indicates how powerful you are. However, the strength that came with his amber eyes was so great, even his comrades looked at him with fear and contempt. He therefore decided to transfer his soul far into the future, hoping to find a paradise that accepts him. He would soon find out that people’s attitude regarding his eye color did change, but not quite the way he had imagined...

The story is set in a fantasy world where one's eye colour indicates their aptitude for magic. Certain eye colours enable one to manipulate specific elements, whereas amber eyes enable one to manipulate all elements with sufficient training. Unfortunately, people with amber eyes were subject to fear and prejudice, since that trait is also shared by demons.
The protagonist, Abel, was a grand magician and the leader of a party of heroes who killed the Demon King. Afterwards, the other members of Abel's party asked him to leave, claiming he was no longer needed. In reality, he knew they secretly feared him due to his amber eyes, but complied anyway. He then went to a secret laboratory he had in a cave and cast a reincarnation spell on himself, planning to awaken 200 years later in a new body he created, resembling himself as a boy. He hoped that, by that time, humanity would've matured enough to be more accepting of people with amber eyes.
200 years later, he wakes up as intended in his laboratory. Soon after, he's approached by a woman whom he realises is Lilith, the daughter of the Demon King he and his former party killed 200 years earlier. Back then, she was just a little girl, so he chose to spare her, and travelled with her for a few weeks until he found her a new home. She now works as a maid for a family of nobles she lives next to and has been awaiting his return in order to repay the debt she feels she owes him.





If correct, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247333/isekai-manga-where-the-mc-is-reincarnated-through-his-own-magic
